# Which of the following pieces of SQL is most efficient

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, date, time

I need to add the date part of `GetDate()` to the time part of a stored `DateTime`.

Naively I thought I could do the following:

```
declare @testTime DateTime = '2013-04-23 13:55:06'
select cast(getdate() as date) + cast(@testTime as time)
```

but this gives the following error:

> Operand data type date is invalid for add operator.

I did some more research and have come up with three possible ways of doing the calculation:

```
declare @testTime DateTime = '2013-04-23 13:55:06'

select dateadd(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GetDate())) + cast(@testTime as time)

select cast(cast(GetDate() as date) as datetime) + cast(@testTime as time)

select dateadd(day, datediff(day, @testTime, GetDate()), @testTime)
```

All three produce the same result but I'm not 100% happy about implementing any of them, though the third way *seems* to be a better way - though I have no evidence for this.

Which (if any) of the three is the most efficient?

Is there a better way?

Comment: The first two don't work for me. The 3rd one is the way I would have done it.

Comment: @JamesAnderson - It could be the SQL Server version. I've updated the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [DATETIMEFROMPARTS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx)

```
select datetimefromparts(
                        datepart(year, getdate()), 
                        datepart(month, getdate()), 
                        datepart(day, getdate()), 
                        datepart(hour, @testTime), 
                        datepart(minute, @testTime), 
                        datepart(second, @testTime),
                        datepart(millisecond, @testTime)
                        )
```

Update:

The first two of your queries.

```
select dateadd(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GetDate())) + cast(@testTime as time)

select cast(cast(GetDate() as date) as datetime) + cast(@testTime as time)
```

require that the database compatibility level is SQL Server 2008(100). If they are executed in compatibility level (110) or (120) you will get

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 The data types datetime and time
>   are incompatible in the add operator.

so you should not consider those at all.

The last query

```
select dateadd(day, datediff(day, @testTime, GetDate()), @testTime)
```

works just fine.

I did a test over 1000000 rows in SQL Server 2014 and the `datetimefromparts` version took 650 ms and `dateadd/datediff` took 350 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on SQL 2005 only:

```
declare @testTime DateTime 
set @testTime = '2013-04-23 13:55:06'
select cast(substring(cast(getdate()as binary(8)),1,4)
            + cast(@testTime as binary(4)) 
            as datetime)
```

Why, how?

```
-- These two have the same last 8 hexadecimal digits,
-- and vary one digit before that
-- This shows that the date and the time 
-- are physically separate 32-bit numbers
select cast(getdate()   as binary(8)) union all 
select cast(getdate()+1 as binary(8)) 
-- last 32-bits: get time
select cast(getdate()   as binary(4)) 
-- first 32-bits: get date
select substring(cast(getdate()   as binary(8)),1,4)
```

Some will argue that I should not be relying on undocumented internals of data-structures in code. That may be true. But if for some reason performance matters enough, I think CAST *should* be quicker. I haven't done any timings.